# Фоновый рисунок на JPanel + компоненты

Tags: java, swing

Всем привет!

Перебрал ворох информации, но не могу понять:

> Как  на панель задать фоновый рисунок так, что бы можно было добавлять
>   другие компоненты (кнопки, текстовые поля и т.д.).

Все варианты какие находил - фон перекрывает все элементы.
На фрейм добавить - без проблем, менеджер компоновки даже удобней, но хочу понять, как сделать для панели?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого вы должны использовать метод paintComponent класса JPanel, пример:

```
class Example extends JPanel{

    private BufferedImage image;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("background.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
    }
}
```

Рекомендую в будущем не связываться с библиотекой swing, т.к она устарела.
Используйте JavaFX в сочетании с Scene Builder.

----------Дополнено----------

```
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel();

private BufferedImage image;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File("background.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    panel.paint(g);
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, panel);
}
```

Comment: Спасиб за совет. Но не смог теперь разобраться, если я панель делю условно на несколько частей, наложением новых панелей. И например мне центральную панель надо заполнить рисунком. Как в таком случае быть?

Comment: Попробуйте как в новом примере, если не получится, то мои знания в этих рамках заканчиваются =)

Comment: При таком добавлении пикча получается маленьким квадратиком. НЕ пойму что делаю не так...